# how to mark the user pair in the mysql database

Tags: mysql-5.7

In my table store two columns of user id, what I am trying to do is mark the user id with pair. For example, the user id like this:

```
user_1_id  user_2_id

  2          3
  3          2
```

we think the two record as one pair(only two user, but the sequence different). I added a new generate column that calculate with `user_1_id + user_2_id`, if the result are the same, it is a pair. But right now I am facing a new problem that it works not perfect because user 0 and 5 was conflict with the record, actually the 0 and 5 was a new pair of user. what should I do to mark the user pair perfectly? I have thinking this problem for hours. this is the real user information in my project:

[image]

This is my table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `spark_game_user_contact` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `target_user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `is_exchange` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_whisper` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pair_flag` bigint(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`user_id` + `target_user_id`)) STORED,
  `updated_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ux_gut` (`game_id`,`user_id`,`target_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=102 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: See [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fkygrHhmDCcdcPgDAGQjhB/2) how to use @Akina's code but with an addition to ensure that id1 != id2!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
-- ...
pair_flag VARCHAR(255) 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT_WS(CHAR(0), 
                                   LEAST(user_id, target_user_id), 
                                   GREATEST(user_id, target_user_id)) STORED,
-- ...
```

If you want this pair to be unique then make this column virtual but add unique index by it.

Comment: Very nice use of `GENERATED` fields to cicumvent the fact that MySQL (< 8.16) doesn't have CHECK constraints! There is one "fly-in-the-ointment" in that your solution doesn't stop id1 being equal to id2 - I [added a calculated field](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fkygrHhmDCcdcPgDAGQjhB/1) `1 /(x - y) which gives a divide by zero error which will stop this! It's a desperate hack though, but hey, [that's MySQL](https://blog.sesse.net/blog/tech/2021-12-05-16-41_leaving_mysql.html)!

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW *your solution doesn't stop id1 being equal to id2* OP have not specified this restriction. The method when incorrect data insertion is prevented by unrelated error generation looks like unsafe. I'd prefer trigger checking for such condition - this allows to generate custom error message (and SQLSTATE error code).

Comment: You're correct - it's not explicitly stated by the OP - but I think it was meant? What does the `CHAR(0)` part of the code do? If I remove it, my strings (1-2) become (-12) - not sure of why ?

Comment: You're correct about it being unsafe - I did say it was a `hack` - but without CHECK constraints, it's the only way to do it declaratively, as far as I can see!

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW *What does the CHAR(0) part of the code do?* This is a char which is used as a delimiter. Its advantage is the fact that this char is never occured in numeric or datetime value and it presents in string value close to never. The delimiter usage is compulsory, without it you may confuse the pairs (1,234) and (12,34), for example.